# Smoothing groups in FBX are always set to 1

Tags: export

I started using the Blender 2.80.75 and when exporting to .FBX with Face/Edge smoothing groups I get all triangles having smoothing group = 1 regardless of the model.

Comment: um, I'm not sure what that means :|

Comment: The question is a bit brief as it lacks details. Please explain what processes you use after exporting. Do you reimport it to blender or to a game engine? (Basically, how do you know it's triangulated?) This could be important for helping others resolve your problem.

Comment: I have created a test mesh with 4 triangles smoothed by pairs (2 smoothing groups). Correct result has to be like that:    LayerElementSmoothing: 0 {
   Version: 102
   Name: ""
   MappingInformationType: "ByPolygon"
   ReferenceInformationType: "Direct"
   Smoothing: *4 {
    a: 8,8,1,1
   } 
  }
but from Blender I got:    LayerElementSmoothing: 0 {
   Version: 102
   Name: ""
   MappingInformationType: "ByPolygon"
   ReferenceInformationType: "Direct"
   Smoothing: *4 {
    a: 1,1,1,1
   } 
  }
Blender export to .OBJ also creates incorrect smoothing groups.